# Loading database records into bootstrap datatable

Tags: sql, asp.net, datatables

I have about 8000 customer records which I have to load all into a bootstrap datatable with ofcourse pagination using AJAX, it works fine,but my challenge is it takes a longer time to finish loading and populating the datatable.
I have to load all the 8000 customers because users may select any at anytime and work with

Please any idea as to how to optimize this,its really slowing down the  asp.net site
Below is my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        var datatableVariable = null
        $(document).ajaxSend(function (event, request, settings) {
            $('#loading-indicator').show();
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            "responsive"; true,
            "serverSide"; true,
            "info"; true,
            "stateSave"; true,
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             url: "CustomerService.asmx/GetCustomer",
             success: function (data) {
                 datatableVariable = $('#dtCustomers').DataTable({
            
                     data: data,
                     columns: [
                         { 'data': 'iD' },
                         { 'data': 'AccountNumber' },
                         { 'data': 'Name' },
                          { 'data': 'FirstName' },
                           { 'data': 'LastName' },
                            { 'data': 'Balance' },
                             { 'data': 'TypeOfAccount' },
                             { 'data': 'Phone' },
                             { 'data': 'SMSAlert' }
                     ],
                     columnDefs: [
                 { "visible": false, "targets": 0 },
                  { "visible": false, "targets": 3 },
                   { "visible": false, "targets": 4 },
                   { "visible": false, "targets": 5},
                   { "visible": false, "targets": 6 },
                   { "visible": false, "targets": 7 },
                   { "visible": false, "targets": 8 }
                     ]
                 });
                 datatableVariable.columns().every(function () {
                     var column = this;
                     $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function () {
                         column.search(this.value).draw();
                     });
                 });
                 $('.showHide').on('click', function () {
                     var tableColumn = datatableVariable.column($(this).attr('data-columnindex'));
                     tableColumn.visible(!tableColumn.visible());
                 });
                 $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                     $('#loading-indicator').hide();
                 });
             }
         });
        });
        $('#dtCustomers').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                     debugger
                     var data = datatableVariable.row(this).data();
                     $(document.getElementById('<%= customerids.ClientID %>')).val(data.iD);
                     $(document.getElementById('<%= lblFnames.ClientID %>')).val(data.FirstName);
                     $(document.getElementById('<%= lblLnames.ClientID %>')).val(data.LastName);
                     $(document.getElementById('<%= lblacc.ClientID %>')).val(data.AccountNumber);
                     $(document.getElementById('<%= lblBals.ClientID %>')).val(data.Balance);
                     $(document.getElementById('<%= acctypes.ClientID %>')).val(data.TypeOfAccount);
                     $(document.getElementById('<%= phone.ClientID %>')).val(data.Phone);
                     $(document.getElementById('<%= smsalert.ClientID %>')).val(data.SMSAlert);
                        var imgDisplay = $get("imgDisplay");
                        imgDisplay.src = "";
                        imgDisplay.style.cssText = "";
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.onload = function () {
                            imgDisplay.style.cssText = "height:150px;width:150px";
                            imgDisplay.src = img.src;
                        };
                        img.src = "<%=ResolveUrl(UploadFolderPath) %>" + data.CustomerPicture;
                     switch (data.TypeOfAccount) {
                         case 0:
                             $('#<%= withid.ClientID %>').hide()
                             break;
                         case 4:
                             $('#<%= withid.ClientID %>').show()

                             break;
                         
                         default:

                     }
        });
        
    </script>
```

Comment: load only needed details of customers. Omit loading image etc. When selecting customer do ajax call and retrieve needed other customer information.

Comment: have you considered server-side pagination or filtering?

Comment: @vinujan,the image is a progress image whiles the data is being loaded, and its not from the database, wouldnt your second recommendation "When selecting customer do ajax call and retrieve needed other customer information" also take time because it will also take time to load the other details from the database using the AJAX call

Comment: @Adyson, can you please assist me with further details how I can achieve this?

Comment: it's really too broad for an SO answer, to implement all that. There seem to be quite a few resources online about the topic already though: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=datatables+server+side+pagination+c%23&oq=datatables+server+side+pag&aqs=chrome.5.69i57j0l5.9055j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks, will check it out